# Clothes don't collide to its parent : a rigid body

Tags: physics, collision, alembic

Description of my scene :
I have a human face mesh (an alembic file in movement) and ropes made with single vert and whith cloths properties  parenting to my face (as child)
When my face moves, ropes move too but its dont collide to my face, they're just passing through this bloody face.

I have tried :

-set clothes "object collision".

-set my face mesh too rigid body / collision.

-duplicate my face mesh and puting at the same child level than my ropes too see if ropes can't react to its parent.

Is that doesnt work because my ropes (clothes properties) is children of my face mesh ?

[image]

[image]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has to do with the fact that the meshes of your cable objects consist of edges and vertices only. I believe for Physics to work between an object with Collision and an Cloth Object, the Cloth object needs to have faces. Otherwise it will not interact with Collision objects.

Also: Visible geometry created by a Skin modifier is in this regard cosmetic only. Even if an object with faces has an Skin modifier, the geometry created by the modifiers also does not interact with Collision objects.

Here is also an image to clarify:
[image]

Selected on this image is a cloth plane with zero thickness, that fell onto a larger collision plane, and then stopped moving. The thickness made by the Skin modifier clips trough the collision plane, and was not directly influenced by physics.

Under it is the same cloth object, but with all the faces removed (so vertices and edges only). If fell right though the collision plane.

Next to it is a similar cloth object but the mesh is a single vertex (it looks like a cube). It did not move or fall at all.

(On a related note: If a Cloth object has faces but still moves through a Collision object, it might help to move the Cloth object, or alter it, so its geometry won't clip (or stick through) the Collision object, since that can cause further clipping or other undesired physics results.)

Comment: thank you for your help! Unfortunately, that sill doesnt work, i've had a screenshot to be more clear about my problem of ropes passing through the face.

Comment: Don't thank me. I owe you an apology. Replacing Collision physics with Rigid Body doesn't work at al, nor should it. (I edited it out of my answer) It temporally seemed it worked, because you cable object stops failing after a while, so it was an illusion cause by coincidence, and frankly my lack of understanding. I did try a bunch of stuff to figure out whats going on though. I think i have a better answer now.